# Exchangability of pointers to member function between different address spaces

Tags: c++, pointers

In The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup, it is said to be possible that a pointer to virtual member function can be passed between different address spaces.

> Because a pointer to a virtual member is a kind of offset, it does not depend on
>   an object's   location in memory. A pointer to a virtual member can therefore be
>   passed between different address spaces as long as the same object layout is used
>   in both. Like pointers to ordinary functions, pointers to non-virtual functions
>   cannot be exchanged between address spaces.

However, i don't understand why pointers to non-virtual functions can't. Like pointers to virtual function, it also acts like an index as Bjarne Stroustrup pointed out.

> However, a pointer to member isn't a pointer to a piece of memory the way a 
>   pointer to a variable or a pointer to a function is. It is more like an offset
>   into a structure or an index into an array, but of course an implementation
>   takes into account the differences between data members, virtual functions,
>   non-virtual functions, etc.

I, of course, understand the differences between virtual function and non-virtual function such as vtbl and so on. However, on every instantiation of class, it's not like the same member functions are assigned again on memory, which means we cannot calculate memory location of member functions depending on memory address of object. In other words, non-virtual functions do not depend on object's location in memory. I think there is only one interface (=functions) and many objects (=maybe representation). If pointers to non-virtual functions act like just an identifier between member functions, it does not make sense it cannot be passed and used between processes.

Comment: regular methods: functions with `this` being passed in `ECX`, called with fixed address. Pseudocode: `func3(&obj);`

Comment: virtual methods: functions with `this` being passed in `ECX`, called via vftable dereference. The vftable pointer is part of the object. Pseudocode: `obj->vftable->func3(&obj);` whereas `func3` is basically just a static offset here and not a global memory address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second quotation, when he talks about pointers-to-members being offsets, this does not include pointers to non-virtual member functions. These are typically implemented as the address of the function code, so they're unlikely to work in another process with its own address space.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly where i'm messed up. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Like pointers to virtual function, it also acts like an index as Bjarne Stroustrup pointed out.

Yes, but an index relative to what?  A pointer to a non-virtual function is an index into the process' address space. The function can be at a different address in different processes, so has different indices. A pointer (which is just a memory address) to a given function in one process could point to something completely different in another process.

A pointer to a virtual function is an offset *relative to the object's address*, so given an object (in any process' own address space) you can find the virtual function by applying the offset to get to the vtbl entry. The objects will be at different addresses in different processes (or even different addresses for different instances in one process) but the offset into the vtbl is fixed.

> In other words, non-virtual functions do not depend on object's location in memory.

Exactly, that's the problem! They depend on the function's location in memory, which is not constant between processes.

> I think there is only one interface (=functions) and many objects (=maybe representation).

Right.

> If pointers to non-virtual functions act like just an identifier between member functions, it does not make sense it cannot be passed and used between processes.

But they don't act "like just an identifier" ... they are pointers. They are addresses in memory. If the function is at address 0x12341234 in one process and at address 0x00011234 in another process, you can't pass the pointer between processes, it won't point to the same thing!

Comment: Because of the second quotation, i don't even try to think of pointers to member functions as ordinary pointers :-(

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation.

Comment: A pointer to a non-virtual member isn't _just_ a pointer (it has a larger `sizeof` for a start) but its first component is just a function pointer. For the Itanium ABI used on many platforms see [Member pointers](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

A non-virtual function is called like a non-member function, just with an extra hidden `this` argument. A pointer to one will contain the address of the function to call - any extra levels of indirection are unnecessary and would slow down the function call and bloat the program.

A virtual function is called by looking up the address in a table associated with the object, whose contents depend on the dynamic type. A pointer to one will contain the index into that table. It can't store the address of any particular function: it may refer to a base class member, which is overridden differently by different derived classes, so that the correct override is only known by virtual lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Think like Bjarne. Hint, he's into performance. He wants all the speed he can get.

If you have a non-virtual method you want to call that method immediately. Any indirection will just slow things down. A virtual method has some indirection built in. It needs to look up which particular type of object it's in using `this` and an offset, which C++ will bypass if it's not needed. In non-virtual functions it's not necessary and is skipped for performance.